# Django python has stopped working when trying to run server after closing it once

Tags: python, django, pycharm

```
python manage.py runserver
```

works fine the first time, but after closing it with ctrl+c, I can't start it up again. I get the error message "Python has stopped working".

This is easily fixed by restarting my computer but it is very inconvenient.

I have also tried the same thing using pycharm, but i get the error message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I am currently on Windows 10.

Comment: post your full traceback of error.

Comment: are you working on python2.7? It is an known bug https://bugs.python.org/issue13081

Comment: I am on python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me and I'm not using Pycharm. I'm using Powershell, Python 3.6 and Django 1.10

If you do

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

then it works.

This was reported but as it's not clear if it's related to Powershell or Django, the report is not allowed to be open.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27766

Comment: After updating python to 3.6.1 the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

First step was to set the environment variable.

1. windows key + pause or Control Panel\System and Security\System
2. Advance system settings (this will open system property)
3. navigate to Advanced tab > Environment variable
4. Edit path - append c:\python36 in variable value field
5. Change 'c:\python36' to ';c:\python36'

then /python manage.py runserver should work

I have no idea why but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can run django with this command

```
python manage.py runserver --skip-checks
```