# django framework runserver not working

Tags: django, python-3.x

Django server isn't working on the command: **`python manage.py runserver`** (on providing the port number as well)
I'm using windows 8, the path is set in environment variables. I've tried re-installing both python and django but it didn't help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try : python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: already tried...the problem persists

Comment: Paste the error

Comment: a dialog box appears saying "python stopped working" and the powershell skips to next line to take input

Comment: I've shared the screenshot with the Question

Comment: Just a suggestion for future projects: consider using a virtual environment while building django projects. It is a lot easier to deal with things and a lot easier to deploy the API, too.

Comment: @MananMehta alright!

Comment: type: python; inside python terminal: import django; then: django.VERSION; Share results

Comment: @Zartch both python version (Python 3.6.1rc1) and django version(1.9.1) are fetched.. but from C directory and I've created the project in a different directory

Comment: Did it work earlier? If yes, try reinstalling Python.

Comment: @MohammedShareefC yes, it did for once (I was using windows 10 then, now I'm using windows 8). I've tried reinstalling python many times...no solution :(

Comment: Hi everyone...got a solution finally :/

Comment: worked with python 2.7 and django 1.9.1

Comment: This is a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125078/django-python-has-stopped-working-when-trying-to-run-server-after-closing-it-onc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share the similar problem. I solved it by just running Python 2.7x.

While working with the runiserver

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

also worked for me - at least for a while. Maybe install an older version of Django?

Answer (score 0):

I've not literally found a solution...
however it worked when I used python 2.7.13 (this creates a folder where you've scripts, easy_install etc., but I couldn't find a folder "Python" when I was using Python 3.6.1)